# Force Chrome to set size of buttons as fixed instead of decimal

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm adding a simple button like this: `<input type="button" value="test" />`

The problem is that Chrome is using decimals to calculate the size of buttons. Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfLnzczt/) and the box-model measurement of the test button.

[image]

The reason it's a problem is that when you dynamically hide a button of height 15.333px and replace it with a div of fixed height 15px the container shrinks by 0.333px and it gives a little visual nudge to the page.

Is there a way to force Chrome to use fixed numbers for all measurements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Chrome, but it's not generating decimal numbers. However, if you're having issues, why don't you just overwrite Chrome's default sizing via CSS? Then, if you swap out the button with a div (of the same height), you'll have a seamless visual experience. Here's an example:

```
input[type=button]{
  line-height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Default sizing will always be inconsistent. It depends on the browser, the available system fonts, ect. It's always ideal to override the default styling with your own code, and to use web fonts to insure that users receive a consistent experience.

Comment: I put a fixed height on all buttons of a certain class and solved the problem. I left the width undefined

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some fiddling honestly I have no idea why chrome's buttons behave the way they do but you could always switch to your own custom buttons which requires that you update the `border` property with something. I also couldn't get chrome's default button to have a different height then their default.

```js
// WARNING ES2015 this won't work on older browsers
document.getElementById("replace").addEventListener("click", () => {
  for(let el of document.body.querySelectorAll(".toggleMe")) {
   el.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=button] {
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
}

.buttonReplacement {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="toggleMe" type="button" value="test" />
<div class="hidden toggleMe buttonReplacement">
test
</div>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="replace" id="replace" />
</p>
```

But that basic example doesn't make for UI-friendly buttons so you may want to add `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus` effects like this:

```js
// WARNING ES2015 this won't work on older browsers
document.getElementById("replace").addEventListener("click", () => {
  for(let el of document.body.querySelectorAll(".toggleMe")) {
   el.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=button] {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

input[type=button]:active {
  background-color: #999;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=button]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.buttonReplacement {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="toggleMe" type="button" value="test" />
<div class="hidden toggleMe buttonReplacement">
test
</div>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="replace" id="replace" />
</p>
```

Note that on user interacted buttons the `cursor: pointer` is a very important property. Also on `:focus` you can also change the `outline` property to none if you want to ditch the outline.